# Shrink UITableView to accommodate another small UIView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a UITableView inside of a UIViewController.
I want to shrink the length of the table view dynamically in the code so that when I click on a row, a view slide down from below and covers a small part of the view form bottom.

Using core animation I am able to slide a UIView from below on top of the table view but I want to resize the table view so that the new UIView that slides from below does not obscure any of the rows in the table view.

I tried changing the height of the frame of the table view but its not working.

Any ideas what am I missing here or what are the common ways to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Simply setting the correct `frame` on your table view should work. Can you quote your code that tries this and doesn't work ?

Comment: Hey it worked ... what I was doing was giving tableView.size.width and tableView.size.height in the parameters for CGRectMake which were returning 0 ... so table was shrinking to 0 by 0 (height by width) ... once I gave literal values, it worked :) ... thanks.

Comment: @DarkDust, please post it in the answer section so that I can select it as correct answer. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setting the correct frame on your table view should work :-)